# Display subprocess using Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

I am still new to python and I have a question about python and Tkinter.I already find the answer about it but i dont understand.
How to display the subprocess output in a Tkinter GUI? I only manage to display it in the terminal, but I want to display in a GUI, please help me for my Final Year Project. Please edit my coding, MASTER

```
import Tkinter
import subprocess


top = Tkinter.Tk()


def helloCallBack():

   print "Below is the output"
   subprocess.call('cat /etc/os-release', shell=True)


B = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Example", command = helloCallBack)

B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you can get the value returned by `.call()` to be a string then you only need to set the value of a `Label`'s `text` attribute to be the string. `Label(root, text=string).pack()`

Comment: Have you done any research? There are similar questions here on this site.

Comment: can u edit my coding because i already find the answer but i do not understand it